# Simple ajax post Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello I have a simple ajax call but I can not see the result. What am I doing wrong ? Thank You.

index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function prova(SelectedFriend){
                $.post("result.php", {Selected:Selected});
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?
            $user="name1";
        ?>
        <div onclick="prova(<? echo $user; ?>)" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <? echo $user; ?>
        </div>
        <?
            $user="name2";
        ?>
        <div onclick="prova(<? echo $user; ?>)" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <? echo $user; ?>
        </div>
        <?
            $user="name3";
        ?>
        <div onclick="prova(<? echo $user; ?>)" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <? echo $user; ?>
        </div>
        <div id="Result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and result.php

```
<?
echo $_POST['Result'];
?>
```

The console of my browser says "Uncaught ReferenceError: name1 is not defined" when I click on name1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$user` must be placed inside simple quotes:

```
<div onclick="prova('<? echo $user; ?>')" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

Also your function is not using the parameter as it should:

```
function prova(SelectedFriend){
    $.post("result.php", {SelectedFriend:SelectedFriend});
    return false;
}
```

And the `result.php` file must be corrected as well:

```
<?php

    echo $_POST['SelectedFriend'];
```

Comment: Now no longer receiving errors, but how to see the results on the div id="Result"? I tried with
$.post("result.php",  {SelectedFriend:SelectedFriend,dataType:"html",success: function(msg){ $("#Result").html(msg);}});
but can's see the results.